# Safari / iOS input keyup event not updating after template is loaded again. Input value cached

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, cordova, caching

I have a phonegap app that uses an autocomplete search feature, attached to an input field. I am using handlebars templates, to make this a one page html app.

When a user types into the input field with class name ".search-key", i have a function that executes on the render of that template that is this:

```
this.render = function() {

    this.$el.html(this.template(pageNames));

    $('.content', this.$el).html(exhibitorListView.$el);

    this.$el.on('keyup', '.search-key', this.findByName);

    return this;
};
```

Which then fires this function:

```
this.findByName = function() {

    var self = this;
    var searchKey = $('.search-key').val();
    var ts = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);

        service.findByName(searchKey,ts).done(function(exhibitors) {

            totalList = exhibitors;

            showPage(1);


        });
};
```

Which then uses my service class to fire the findByName function that loops through the SQL to pull the results that match what the user is typing.

This works fine the first time. But after a user clicks on a result, and it pulls up a template page for the result, and they click the back button which looks like this in the html page:

```
<a class="btn btn-link btn-nav pull-left menu-btn" id="backButton"   href="javascript:history.back()">
  <span class="icon icon-left-nav"></span>
</a>
```

When the search page is returned to the view, the text last entered into the input is stuck in the cache, even though its not displayed on the screen (I can see the values in the console) and as the user types, the new text is not updated in the app. After every keyup, the value is just repeated of whats stuck in the cache, and the results dont change.